# How can I calculate how much time it will take to transfer 10 TB at different speeds?

Tags: data-transfer

How long will it take to transfer 10TB of data at 60Mbps, 80Mbps, 1000Mbps ?

Comment: I like the question. +1. Regards,

Comment: Just to make clear, do you mean Megabits (as you have written) or MegaBytes?

Answer (score 5):

To calculate transfer time divide the amount of data by transfer speed like this:

(10 terabytes) / (60 Mbps) = 16.1817284 days
(10 terabytes) / (80 Mbps) = 12.1362963 days
(10 terabytes) / (1000 Mbps) = 23.3016889 hours

Or have google do it for you like [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=10TB%2F+1000Mbps)

Comment: It's actually a little longer than that, as there's transmission overhead on the line as well.

Answer (score 4):

WolframAlpha is great for this kind of calculations : [10 terabytes at 60mbps](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10+terabytes+at+60mbps)